# How can I know if my pc is 'MBR' or 'GBT'

Tags: mbr

when I want to install windows 10 on my pc, I burnt .ISO file on flash USB , as  ' GPT ', but firstly my pc can not see it while installing windows, then I format it and burn it as 'MBR' , so that my pc saw it and I install windows 10.
Questions : How can I know if my pc is 'MBR' or 'GBT' .if my pc can not run current operating system and I need to change operating system and install other OS .
in other words:
can I know that from bios menu or other interface without run old OS

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Have you tried to google this? What did your research turn up?

Comment: Please google your question, plenty of answers.

Comment: In a nutshell: Windows in the (strongly) recommended UEFI mode - all PCs since ~2012 - strictly requires GPT partitioning (yes, it's about the partitioning type of the target drive, not your PC as a whole) and strictly requires the old MBR ("msdos") partitioning type for BIOS or Legacy/CSM installations, something you should AVOID in this day and age.